# What does one-tangle says in an n-qubit system?

Tags: entanglement

One-tangle is negativity with respect to qubit x.

I know in a 3 qubit system if one-tangle with respect to qubit x is 0, then qubit x is separatable.

Is this statement generalized for n-qubit systems? I mean in an n-qubit system if one-tangle with respect to qubit x is 0, then the qubit x is separatable from the entire system?

Comment: What is one-tangle? is it $n$-tangle from knot theory? I have only heard about it superficially but never in the context of entanglement. Can you link resources?

Comment: please see https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49/tutorial-how-to-use-tex-mathjax-to-render-math-notation to render math on the site. Also, please link your sources

Comment: @fDGod you can read about monogamy of entanglement in terms of negativity, see the below link https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0702127